# TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I am trying to preview .docx file using react-file-viewer

```
<FileViewer
    fileType={'docx'}
    filePath={this.state.file} //this.state.file has path of the url data
    id="output-frame-id"
    allowFullScreen={true}
/>
```

When the user clicks on the .docx file for preview it throws an exception :

TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

and points to the code below

```
let srcData = URL.createObjectURL(this.response); // It contains a Response type of blob
error at this line ---> document.querySelector('#output-frame-id').src = srcData;
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: you might wanna use `ref`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/plangrid/react-file-viewer

[source code](https://github.com/plangrid/react-file-viewer/blob/f55ce66e49e15244a6c30d77e52acbbdad064d36/src/components/file-viewer.jsx#L85)

```
 FileViewer.propTypes = {
      fileType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      filePath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      onError: PropTypes.func,
      errorComponent: PropTypes.element,
      unsupportedComponent: PropTypes.element,
    };
    
    FileViewer.defaultProps = {
      onError: () => null,
      errorComponent: null,
      unsupportedComponent: null,
    };
```

I don't see in documentation **id** field, maybe that's why your selector return `null`.

You should use only this field: `fileType`, `filePath`, `onError`, `errorComponent`, `unsupportedComponent`.

If you want for some reason DOM manipulations with element, for this you can wrap your element by `div`:

```
<div id="output-frame-id"
    <FileViewer
        fileType={'docx'}
        filePath={this.state.file} //this.state.file has path of the url data
        allowFullScreen={true}
    />
</div>
```

But i recommend use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: @AniketYadav good,  you can set my answer like right

Comment: Can you also give example with refs ? While using it with id the document gets zoomed in and  displays only half of the contents.

Comment: @AniketYadav refs just get you DOM element, problem with zoom it's another

Comment: When i remove id element from div it is giving error but after closing the error window file is rendered perfectly. As soon as I insert id element in div..no error shows up and the docx file contents are hafed and zoomed. Any idea why this is the case ?

Comment: i think it's some problem with `position` of your `div` with `id`.

Comment: @AniketYadav you can create another question with https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because

```
document.querySelector('#output-frame-id') // equal to null
```

Can you check in developer tool does React really render element with such id - **output-frame-id**? I know you have this id in your component, but it not necessary that React will render it... It depends of realization of FileViewer, this component might not support id attribute because this is a custom component.

I am not sure but, you can try to use:

1. use refs
2. use colon before id

```
:id="output-frame-id"
```